# What is the most efficient way to get the highest and the lowest values in a Array

Tags: javascript

is there something like PHP: `max()` in javascript?

lets say i have an array like this:

```
[2, 3, 23, 2, 2345, 4, 86, 8, 231, 75]
```

and i want to return the highest and the lowest value in this array. What is the fastest way to do that?

i have tried:

```
function madmax (arr) {
  var max = arr[0],
      min = arr[1]

  if (min > max) {
      max = arr[1]
      min = arr[0]   
  }

  for (i=1;i<=arr.length;i++){
     if( arr[i] > max ) {
       max = arr[i]
     }else if( arr[i] < min ) {
       min = arr[i]
     }
}

return max, min
}

madmax([123, 2, 345, 153, 5, 98, 456, 4323456, 1, 234, 19874, 238, 4])
```

Is there a simpler way retrieve the max and min value of a array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Applying](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply) the [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Math/Max) and [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Math/Min) built-in methods can be really fast:

```
var array = [2, 3, 23, 2, 2345, 4, 86, 8, 231, 75];
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, array); // 2345
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, array); // 2
```

Comment: And then the exact same for min `Math.min.apply(Match, array);`

Comment: @meo, you are welcome, check this simple [performance test](http://jsbin.com/uyani3/2) between applying `Math.max` and your `madmax` function.

Comment: madmax looks pretty bad :P sometimes, but just sometimes i should ask before i code

Comment: Thanks! However how can I get the array's key returned instead?